# QGIS 3.4.6 "Network access is disabled" on WiFi only

Tags: qgis-3, network

I get this error message when connecting to OWS from GeoServer in QGIS 3.4.6 LTR on Windows 10 on WiFi only.

> Failed to download capabilities:
>   Download of capabilities failed: Network access is disabled.

As soon as LAN is plugged in, OWS connects immediately. QGIS 2.18.24 on same device connects to same OWS on WiFi without problem.

Has anyone seen this before / can suggest a resolution?